# [unixODBC]Missing database name in call to CC_connect

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 x64, and I've set up both PostgreSQL and ODBC. Or I almost have; when I execute some scheme code from guile, it outputs the following error:

```
Can't perform SQLConnect rc=-1(201) [unixODBC]Missing database name in call to CC_connect.
```

I think that I made some pretty simple mistake, but I can't figure out which files i should tinker with to fix it.
So, my question is: which files are being looked at to find that database name, or, failing to answer that, is there a way to trace guile code?

Okay, update: the logs look like this:

```
CONN ERROR: func=original_CC_connect, desc='', errnum=201, errmsg='Missing database name in call to CC_connect.'
            ------------------------------------------------------------
            henv=0x3dec0d0, conn=0x3ffd280, status=0, num_stmts=16
            sock=(nil), stmts=0x3ffddd0, lobj_type=-999
            ---------------- Socket Info -------------------------------
CONN ERROR: func=PGAPI_Connect, desc='Error on CC_connect', errnum=201, errmsg='Missing database name in call to CC_connect.'
           ------------------------------------------------------------
            henv=0x3dec0d0, conn=0x3ffd280, status=0, num_stmts=16
            sock=(nil), stmts=0x3ffddd0, lobj_type=-999
            ---------------- Socket Info -------------------------------
DSN info: DSN='triples',server='',port='',dbase='',user='',passwd=''
          onlyread='',protocol='',showoid='',fakeoidindex='',showsystable=''
          conn_settings='(null)', conn_encoding='(null)'
          translation_dll='',translation_option=''
conn = 0x3fff340, PGAPI_Connect(DSN='triples', UID='opencog_user', PWD='xxxxx')
Driver Version='09.03.0300,201405140001'
Global Options: fetch=100, socket=4096, unknown_sizes=0, max_varchar_size=255, max_longvarchar_size=8190
                disable_optimizer=0, ksqo=1, unique_index=1, use_declarefetch=0
                text_as_longvarchar=1, unknowns_as_longvarchar=0, bools_as_char=1 NAMEDATALEN=64
                extra_systable_prefixes='dd_;', conn_settings='(null)' conn_encoding=''
```

---

Edit: the whole issue is available [on github](https://github.com/opencog/atomspace/issues/881)

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you try to connect?  From the DSN info, I see that none of the required fields (server, dbase, user, ...) is filled in.  This indicates that the required parameters are not known from the connecting entity.

Comment: Indeed.  In fact, I'm trying to run two different pieces of code, one in C++ and one in scheme, and both eventually report the same error. I can provide alink to a github issue discussing the same problem.

Comment: I wonder : Did you  define a dsn in the odbc.ini file?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen, please review the github issue. In short, if you mean "is there a DSN line in your `~/.odbc.ini` file", then no. But if you mean "Is there a database name in your `~/.odbc.ini`", then sure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see in the github issue (I did not see the sources), the problem is in the configuration file.
It seems that upon connection, all you specify is the DSN name '`triples`'. So, the system will look after a section named '`triples`' in your config file.  The `obdc.ini` file can reside in the user directory or in `/etc`.  This means you should have in one of these files (I suspect `/etc/odbc.ini`) something like:

```
[triples]
Description      = Whatever
Driver           = PostgreSQL
Database         = yourdatabse
Servername       = yourserver
Port             = 5432
Username         = yourusername
Password         = yourpassword
```

Comment: That seems like a reasonable thing to suppose, but my setup has no DSN called `triples`; I didn't create it myself, and it is not supposed to exist.
I have no idea why it's the name of the DSN that appears in the logs, but, as I understand it, there's nothing in the current code to warrant looking for a DSN named `triples`.
Appropriately, neither `~/.odbc.ini` nor `/etc/odbc.ini` has a definition for it.